# Firebase UI is displaying null for displayName under the user object

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am using the Firebase UI Web to allow users to signup to my Firebase project. I am then using a cloud function (in Node.js):

`exports.newUserUpdate = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {})`

to then send the newly created user an email. When I read in `user.displayName` or console.log the `user` object, it displays the `displayName` as null. This seemingly looks like the `displayName` was not submitted on the signup.

I am using Firebase UI Web 3.4.1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is a known issue:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/95

When creating a user, the following APIs are called in succession:

- `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` to create the email/password user.
- `user.updateProfile` to set the display name on the user

`onCreate` event is triggered in the first call when the display name is not yet known.

See reference here [`updateProfile`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#updateprofile)

Comment: I confirm. You can get the user data inside the onCreate function:
`admin.auth().getUser(userRecord.uid);`
I don't know if it's a good solution nor if the user data will always be populated (depends if the `user.updateProfile` is called before the `admin.auth().getUser(userRecord.uid);`) but it works in my case

Answer (score 0):

The same problem I face while registering users with email and password, but I don't use cloud functions to do that. See reference here [updateProfile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#updateprofile)

I use this method to update user name `user.updateProfile({displayName: name})` after creating user with email & password.

```
const res = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
const user = res.user;

// once we get user object then update user display name using following method
await user.updateProfile({displayName: name})
```

`createUserWithEmailAndPassword` only takes two arguments `email` & `password`. That's why displayName is null in the user object. To fix that we have to run `user.updateProfile()` to update user name.

Answer (score -1):

[Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data) says,

> #### Set an authentication state observer and get user data
>
> For each of your app's pages that need information about the signed-in user,
>   attach an observer to the global authentication object. This observer
>   gets called whenever the user's sign-in state changes.
>
> Attach the observer using the onAuthStateChanged method. When a user
>   successfully signs in, you can get information about the user in the
>   observer.
>
> ```
> firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
>   if (user) {
>     // User is signed in.
>     var displayName = user.displayName;
>     var email = user.email;
>     var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
>     var photoURL = user.photoURL;
>     var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
>     var uid = user.uid;
>     var providerData = user.providerData;
>     // ...
>   } else {
>     // User is signed out.
>     // ...
>   }
> });
> ```

Comment: Yep, although this is not relevant. I am asking how come the ```displayName``` does not push to the user object when using the FirebaseUI Web to sign up. When I use this, ```user.displayName``` is null.